# div element and image not aligned

Tags: html, css

I am creating a lightbox. For this, I need a box with comments to be on the right of the actual image.

However, I cannot figure how to make the comment box begin at top of the image, and end at the bottom of the image.

I've put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5u6sav7/) that demonstrates the problem. Below is the same code.

```css
.lightbox-container .lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99991;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}


.lightbox-container .lightbox span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
}


.lightbox-container .lightbox img {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .5;
}

.lightbox-container .lightbox .lightbox-comments {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="lightbox-container">
    <div class="lightbox">
        <span class="icon ion-chevron-left"></span>

        <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/600x800/?text=Picture" />
        <div class="lightbox-comments">
            A comments box
        </div>
        
        <span class="icon ion-chevron-right"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use absolute positionning with top and bottom at 0 on your comment box. But you also need a wrapper around the image and the comment box who has a relative position.

You can see a snippet bellow.

Hope it helps.

```css
.lightbox-container .lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99991;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

/*ADDED*/
.lightbox-container .lightbox .wrapper {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
/*/ADDED*/

.lightbox-container .lightbox span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
}


.lightbox-container .lightbox img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width:100%; /*ADDED*/
  display: block;/*Changed to avoid small margin bellow the image*/
  cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .5;
}

.lightbox-container .lightbox .lightbox-comments {
  position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; /*ADDED*/
  width: 200px;
  /*height: 500px;*/
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox-container">
    <div class="lightbox">
        <span class="icon ion-chevron-left"></span>
        <!--Wrapper added-->
        <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/600x800/?text=Picture" />
        <div class="lightbox-comments">
            A comments box
        </div>
        </div>
        <span class="icon ion-chevron-right"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place all children inside `.lightbox-container .lightbox` as `inline-block`, then vertically align them in the middle by adding this to your stylesheet:

```
.lightbox-container .lightbox > * {
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You'll also need to change the height of `.lightbox-container .lightbox .lightbox-comments` to 100% to give a dynamic height.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5u6sav7/1/)

Comment: This is almost what I am trying to achieve. However, in your fiddle, if the image height shrinks, the commentary box is too tall. Here's a fiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/c5u6sav7/2/